# Cube Preference in the Same Position

Tags: modeling

I'm trying to get two cubes in 1 spot to have only one showing. I feel like there should be a setting for view preference (I've tried adding one collection to a view layer and adding the collection with the other cube to a different view layer but it doesn't really make it clear which is first and it rendered with these same glitches both ways) of objects/collections. I know I can make the scale of the cube I want to see 1.005 (I've tried 1.01 and the glitches are minimized but still noticeable in a .glb viewer) or bigger in general, but this is not preferred.
I know I can delete the cube I don't want to show, but some cubes need to stay and some need to have the other collection show, so I essentially need to automate which collection is viewed on the outside, even though a lot of objects have the same exact dimensions/positions. Is there a setting for mesh surface depth maybe? Or is there a setting for the surface of an object that might make this go away?
If anyone could help me I'd appreciate it so much, thank you!

I guess StackExchange doesn't allow video uploads, but here's a link to the video of what's happening:
https://youtu.be/xrnCGk3NM2E

Comment: Hello and welcome. While files, images, and external videos or links may be helpful additions they should not be the only way to obtain information about your issue. Don't make understanding your question rely on downloading a file, watching a video or visiting an external site. Use the builtin tools to upload [images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) or [gifs](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963), along with thoroughly explaining the problem in written form so it can be indexed and searched for thus helping future visitors with similar issues.

Comment: why don't you just use "disable in render" and keyframe that?